# jquery tr click input radio checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked and can't find a simple answer for my question.
I click on one of the `TR` then click on the other `TR` and it works fine but after the two have been clicked it no longer recognized the clicking on a row.
Any help?
Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Yes
            <input type='radio' name='test' value='yes' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>No
            <input type='radio' name='test' value='no' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here is the jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('table tr').click(function () {
        $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to be able to click a row of a table and have the radio button checked. After one row has been clicked it no longer can be clicked.

Comment: If you're using radio buttons, if another row is clicked then the previously clicked row SHOULD be unselected. If this isn't the inteded behavior, you should probably be using checkboxes instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be setting the checked property via. [**`prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqCCH/)

Comment: Also put a style on the td of cursor:pointer; Just make it look a little nicer :)

Comment: FYI: to Meta viewers, I didn't mean he *literally* copy-pasted my answer, I simply meant he posted the same solution after a considerable amount of time (plus after an extensive question edit  which took place a minute and a half after I'd already answered), and that there is no point in cluttering up questions with duplicate answers. Sorry to Christopher if I offended him, I retract my comments and I'll think twice about posting any negative comments from now on.

Comment: +1. It is right and you answered very fast.

Comment: Any way we can achieve this without using JavaScript?  For e.g. using the label for attribute.

Comment: @Sid nope, you'll need to use JavaScript